# miktex 2.9, l3kernel installation fails

Tags: xetex, installing, miktex, expl3

I freshly installed 2.9

I tried to compile a XeLatex document, which works fine on my work computer.

I got the following error:

```
expl3.sty missing.
```

It tries to install l3kernel

```
starting package maintenance...
installation directory: "C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9"
package repository: http://distrib-coffee.ipsl.jussieu.fr/pub/mirrors/ctan/system/win32/miktex/tm/packages/
lightweight database digest: b641b9d295dbd4c2d5caa951cd9d95e3
going to download 6240193 bytes
going to install 44 file(s) (1 package(s))
downloading http://distrib-coffee.ipsl.jussieu.fr/pub/mirrors/ctan/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/l3kernel.tar.lzma...
6177780 bytes, 227.61 KB/Sec
visiting repository http://distrib-coffee.ipsl.jussieu.fr/pub/mirrors/ctan/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/...
repository type: remote package repository
loading lightweight database...
downloading http://distrib-coffee.ipsl.jussieu.fr/pub/mirrors/ctan/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/miktex-zzdb1-2.9.tar.lzma...
130729 bytes, 141.07 KB/Sec
lightweight database digest: b641b9d295dbd4c2d5caa951cd9d95e3
xelatex.EXE: The operation could not be completed because the following file failed verification:
xelatex.EXE: 
xelatex.EXE: C:\Users\y\AppData\Local\Temp\mikAB2F.tmp
======================================================================


! LaTeX Error: File `expl3.sty' not found.
```

I get the same error when I try to install the package via the package manager

```
The operation could not be completed because the following file failed verification:
C:\Users\y\AppData\Local\Temp\mikD002.tmp
```

Comment: This might be a MiKTeX bug; while I didn’t try reinstalling, I got the same error error message about files with a similar name in the equivalent directories on two different computers when I tried to update.

Comment: There seems to be currently quite a lot of problems with the package installation in miktex. Some of the checksums are faulty (and some of the mirrors are down).

Comment: I have the same problem and tried few different mirrors with no luck.

Comment: So I just wait a few days and then I try to reinstall everything...

Comment: @dziadgba: Things seems to be back to normal. I just could run the update which failed two days ago.

Comment: I could also successfully update on both machines.